# Why isn't Pull showing on TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, pull

[image]

For some reason the pull request isn't showing. I had some conflicts that I resolved. It insisted that I pushed/committed the code but I didn't. Is that something I need to do first? Is that why pull isn't showing here as it usually does?

Comment: Please post code directly, not a link to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still in the middle of a merge. Either resolve and commit the merge or abort it.

[image]

Comment: In my case it wasn't a merge but a bisect. Reset bisect, then switch back to branch if needed.