# TortoiseGit stuck in "merge mode", cannot restore pull option in menu

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-merge-conflict

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935175/why-isnt-pull-showing-on-tortoisegit) about why the pull option in the TortoiseGit menu is missing - a (conflicting?) merge is in process, so pull is hidden from the context menu. But when I try both `Resolve...` and `Revert...` in the menu, there are no files there, so there's no way to fix it. Tried both `Clean up` and hard resetting the branch, but to no avail. And there's no `Abort merge` option either.

Pull is available if you show log and right click on an entry, so there's a workaround, but it would be nice to restore it to the menu. Using version 2.15.0.0.

Edit: Have tried command line, but there simply is no merge going on according to Git, so it doesn't do anything:

```
> git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing)
```

Comment: Use the command line instead? Or just abort the merge?

Comment: Have you tried a hard reset?

Comment: Yes, there is no merge going on according to Git, only according to TortoiseGit apparently.

Comment: what does `git status` say?

Comment: Does pull show up if you hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key?

Comment: Nothing special according to git status: 
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 14 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: @MrTux it does! Any idea what that means?

Comment: It seems as if have adjusted the context menu settings: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel-extended

Comment: @MrTux you're right, it was unchecked in context menu, but checked in context menu 2. Please post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if have adjusted the context menu settings:
https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel-extended